# Алгоритм умножения чисел методом сдвига

Tags: алгоритм

Как перемножить целые числа используя операцию битового сдвига и операцию сложения?

Comment: Сдвиг влево на 1 бит приводит к умножению на 2. Если надо больше чем на 2 то комбинируйте сдвиги и сложение

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Предположим, надо умножить число `a` на константу 13.

Двоичное представление 13 = 8 + 4 + 1 = 1101<sub>2</sub>.

Если пронумеровать биты справа налево (от младших к старшим) начиная с нуля, получится, что установлены биты 0 (самый правый), 2 и 3.

Соответственно:

```
a * 13 = a << 3 + a << 2 + a << 0
```

Или, в более привычной форме:

```
a * 13 = a * 8 + a * 4 + a
```

Обычно такие оптимизации при умножении на константу производит компилятор (это одна из самых старых оптимизаций). Для того, чтобы умножить на любое целое число, можно сдвигать это число вправо на 1 бит, и тестировать самый младший бит:

```
int a = ...;
int b = ...;

int result = 0;
while (b != 0) {
  if (b & 0x1 == 0x1)
    result += a;

  b >>= 1;
  a <<= 1;
}
```

Здесь на каждой итерации `a` умножается на 2, а `b` нацело делится на 2. Условие `b & 0x1 == 0x1` проверяет, установлен ли младший бит у текущего значения `b` — фактически, является ли `b` нечётным числом.

Чтобы стало понятно, что здесь происходит, можно подставить знакомое нам число 13 вместо `b`.

1. `13 & 1` равно 1, поскольку 13 нечётное число. Значит, 0-й бит установлен. Прибавляем оригинальное значение `a`.
2. `13/2 = 6` в случае целочисленного деления. Увеличиваем `a` в два раза.
3. `6 & 1` равно 0 — 6 чётное число. Значит, 1-й бит сброшен. Не прибавляем удвоенное значение `a`.
4. `6/2 = 3`. Увеличиваем `a` ещё в два раза.
5. `3 & 1` равно 1, так как 3 нечётное число. Значит, 2-й бит установлен. Прибавляем учетверённое значение `a`.
6. `3/2 = 1` при делении нацело.  Увеличиваем `a` в два раза.
7. `1 & 1` равно 1, так как 1 нечётное число. 3-й бит установлен. Прибавляем увосьмерённое значение `a`.
8. `1/2 = 0` при делении нацело. Получив 0, заканчиваем алгоритм.

Битовые операции, выполняются намного быстрее умножения и деления, поэтому *теоретически* это умножение производится быстро. Однако на практике низкоуровневое умножение реализованное в микропроцессоре, выполняется гораздо быстрее, может быть даже на порядок или два.

Поэтому практического смысла такой код наверное не имеет.

Answer (score 0):

Дано: числа `a` и `b`, требуется найти `c` = `a` * `b`

Алгоритм вычисления произведения в двоичной арифметике:

`i` - сдвиг

```
i = 0
пока a не равно нулю:
    если i-й бит a не равен нулю:
        с = с + b
        обнуляем i-й бит a
    b = b сдвинутое на один разряд влево (в сторону увеличения веса)
    i = i + 1
```

Можно не считать позиции сдвига, а сдвигать `a` вправо и проверять только первый бит (так делали на ассемблерах, не поддерживающих умножение)

```
пока a не равно нулю:
    если 1-й бит a не равен нулю:
        с = с + b
    b = b сдвинутое на один разряд влево (в сторону увеличения веса)
    a = a сдвинутое на один разряд вправо
```